# How to deliver YouTube content from WordPress into an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress

I have a question.  A client of mine wants to create an iOS app. His website is a WordPress blog and has a lot of video content from the likes of YouTube, Vimeo, things like that.

The app needs to download the content and display it in the app.

To do this, I will be using JSON API to get all the latest post content in a JSON format.

There is a potential problem with this and is the subject of my question;

Nearly all of the video content is in Flash.  Yes, this is slowly changing; but for the meantime I'm pulling in HTML/flash content from a WordPress blog and needing it to display in the app.

So, obviously displaying Flash content in an app isn't going to work because it either needs HTML5/webview or because it needs the actual Flash player; or maybe I have this wrong?

The only concern I have is that the app ends up being a bunch of HTML5/webviews and ends up being rejected; but I am confident I can resolve this.

Anyway, my question is: How do you deliver YouTube/Flash content that is emanating from a WordPress blog and display this in an iOS app, or is this not possible without some serious API hacking?

### The steps

1. Pull in JSON from WordPress blog using JSON API plugin
2. Read the JSON in Objective-C
3. Display the HTML in a webview

Problem: What do I do about the video content when its Flash?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because flash no longer exists so the question is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

To display Web video, it's easy just to use a WebView and an object tag a la :

```
<object width="300" height="200" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
  <param name="source" value="kua_bay.png">
  <param name="href" value="kua_bay.mp4">
  <param name="target" value="myself">
  <param name="controller" value="false">
  <param name="autoplay" value="false">
  <param name="scale" value="aspect">
  <embed width="300" height="200" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" src="kua_bay.png" href="kua_bay.mp4" target="myself" controller="false" autoplay="false" scale="aspect" title="QuickTime">
</object>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused -- I am pulling in a JSON feed from a Wordpress blog.  The code being pulled in would be in JSON, but I can spit out HTML format using a webview; this is fine, but there is no guarantee that there is any video content.  Are you saying I just put the HTML in a webview and it'll be okay as it is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't just put in HTML object tags after the fact, I don't want to be sniffing every incoming HTML to find a tag and then replace it with the object tag.  Please clarify; are you saying that if there is an object tag in a webview Apple iPhone will know automatically how to resolve and display it?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the use-case, but this is what I'm suggesting:

Step 1: Grab your JSON feed, parse and find that you want to display "foo.mp4" (I'm not going to deal with the Flash aspect, because I don't know your plan for dealing with that)

Step 2: Retrieve some string that is a template for showing video in a UIWebView (<html><body><object ...etc...></body></html> or whatever). 

Step 3: Put "foo.mp4" into the template by string replacement

Step 4: Set the content of your WebView using `LoadHTMLString:` 

Step 5: Profit!

Comment: But, yes, the object tag I put in above is verbatim from a content page in one of my apps. I don't do anything special to display video (all the content is local, in my case, but that's neither here nor there).

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the youtube and vimeo links and replace it on your side with code that properly embeds their ios/html5 versions.

Comment: I guess that would be feasible. But it means sniffing/regexing the youtube, vimeo or other links doesn't it?

Comment: I think I'll leave it for now and just tell the client its strictly not possible unless there is custom fields with all the video links inside it (sorta list an assets list) so then I could grab the necessary URLs and do it that way.

Comment: I recently developed a solution for a client that did exactly that. Parsed YT videos into custom fields and it is then accessible via special RSS feed. But it requires code on Wordpress side.